# jQuery remove spaces on blur not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

The replace function I'm using works as I've tested it in the console but it does not work at all on blur. How can I fix that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Ensure spaces are not entered between tags
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#item_keywords').blur(function(){
            $(this).val().replace(/^\s+$/,"");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the current result? Does it do anything at all? Have you used firebug / chrome console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Please show an example of what you are trying to achieve, including some markup, the answer given is correct if it is a normal input tag, if that doesn't work for you, then something else is wrong, that people cannot guess...

Comment: Could you create a jfiddle for that? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Val I thought he would best learn it by doing it self. You know, like the whole "Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today. Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime." thing :-)

Comment: @tim first you need to teach him how to feed himself though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have removed the spaces but u have not assigned them any where :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#item_keywords').unbind('blur').bind('blur',function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s+$/,""));
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response Val. Unfortunately this isn't working. As i say I tested it in the console with my above solution, and it worked fine, but I've tried your way as it makes sense, but nope nothing :S

Comment: in that case u might have to bind the blur function and if this is the only thing u need for that input u should use unbind aswell check updated answer

Comment: btw are you sure u have included the jquery core file? and checked if there is any script in coz sometimes we assume it is loaded properly :)

Comment: my fault. it does need to wrapped in the val() as u suggested. but it also wasn't matching the pattern. i removed the ^ and $ (which I thought meant match from the start of the string until the end?) and now it works.

Comment: well regex is my weakest subject but o well :)

Comment: apparently ^\s+$ would match one or more spaces immediately following the start of the string with the end of the string coming immediately after the space(s). such as "     " (without the quotes) would match. that's what I've taken from a quick read of: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#business_email').unbind('blur').bind('blur',function(){
                var a = $(this).val().trim();
                $(this).val(a + '.');
                $(this).val(a);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mytextbox").blur(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,''));
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```