# How to make active admin email search to trim preceeding suceeding spaces in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, customization, activeadmin

i have active admin in my rails application. while searching the users based on their email,in the right side of the page(filters), if i enter any email that contains preceding and succeeding spaces,then the results are empty

i want to customise the active admin filter search, in such a way that it trims these preceding and succeeding spaces and provide the results while searching. how can i implement this. as i am new to the active admin i do not know how to customise it.

```
   def override_search
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be overkill, but one way would be to [use a ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers). Another way would be to define a [custom formtastic input](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs). However, the easiest way might be to [attach some JavaScript to the input onBlur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040757/jquery-remove-spaces-on-blur-not-working) to trim any content before submission.